# Struts 1.3: forward outside the application context?

Tags: java, struts

Struts 1.3 application.  Main website is NOT served by struts/Java.  I need to forward the result of a struts action to a page in the website, that is outside of the struts context.  Currently, I forward to a JSP in context and use a meta-refresh to forward to the real location.  That seems kinda sucky.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't "forward", in the strict sense. Just call `sendRedirect()` on the `HttpServletResponse` object in your `Action` class's `execute()` method and then, `return null`.

Alternately, either call `setModule()` on the `ActionForward` object (that you are going to return) or set the path to an absolute URI.

Comment: My understanding is that an absolute URI that doesn't include the host/port is always considered relative to the app context.

What does setModule() do?  It's not clearly documented, and seems like "/whatever" is still relative to the app context?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing response.sendRedirect().

Answer (score 0):

If this was still in the web application, you could use [ServletContext.RequestDispatcher](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html)?  That's how the Struts doForward() method works.  However, to go outside Struts/Java, you need the sendRedirect().

```
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(uri);
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: You're right - I misread the question.  I will edit my answer, but leave for completeness.